# How to handle triple (or configured numbers) of tap gesture on Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` class for handling some simple gestures on my app. And it's works perfectly.

But now I'm faced with a problem of handling multiple tap gesture.
I Just want to configure NumbersOfTaps and handle appropriate gesture.

But can't find any details or notes How to implement it on Andoid or Xamarin.Android documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
            DateTime _firstTap;
            int _tapCount = 0;
            const int TAP_COUNT_TRESHOLD = 5; //number of taps
            const int TIME_TRESHOLD 200; //ms time

            protected override void OnResume()
            {
                myButton.Clicked += ButtonTapped;
            }

            protected override void OnPause()
            {
                myButton.Clicked -= ButtonTapped;
            }

            void ButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e){

                var time = Math.Round((DateTime.Now - _firstTap).TotalMilliseconds, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

                if (time > TIME_TRESHOLD)
                {
                    _tapCount = 1;
                    _firstTap = DateTime.Now;
                }
                else
                    _tapCount++;

                if (_tapCount == TAP_COUNT_TRESHOLD)
                {
                   //do your logic here
                }
            }
```

Time limit and number of clicks are configurable.

Answer (score 2):

Use that code, I do not believe if it is good approach but it works. Check it out.

```
long milliSeconds = 0;
        var tapCount = 0;
        var millisecondsPeriod = 200;
        button.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            if (milliSeconds == 0) {
                milliSeconds = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
                tapCount++;
            } else {
                var currMill = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond - milliSeconds;
                if (currMill < millisecondsPeriod) {
                    milliSeconds = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
                    tapCount++;
                    if (tapCount == 3) {
                        Toast.MakeText (this, "triple", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
                    }
                } else {
                    tapCount = 0;
                    milliSeconds = 0;
                }
            }
        };
```

You can change the millisecondsPeriod how you wish.